# How to configure the datetime format in a System.ServiceModel.ClientBase

Tags: .net, wcf

I'm trying to call a web service with a call like follows. It fails.

```html
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <createObject>
            <clientInfo>
                <firstName>Adam</firstName>
                <lastName>Smith</lastName>
                <sex>M</sex>
                <birthDate>2000-12-23T00:00:00</birthDate>
                <language>EN</language>
                <email>adam@smith.com</email>
                <sendEmail>false</sendEmail>
                <phone>0123456789</phone>
            </clientInfo>   
        </createObject>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Then I find out that the date is in wrong format, it should be like this 2000-12-23T00:00:00Z
That little Z in the end makes a difference and the call like this succeeds:

```html
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <createObject>
            <clientInfo>
                <firstName>Adam</firstName>
                <lastName>Smith</lastName>
                <sex>M</sex>
                <birthDate>2000-12-23T00:00:00Z</birthDate>
                <language>EN</language>
                <email>adam@smith.com</email>
                <sendEmail>false</sendEmail>
                <phone>0123456789</phone>
            </clientInfo>   
        </createObject>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

So my challenge now is to configure the call or the client in a way that the date appears in the correct format.
Does anyone have any suggestion? Thanks in advance

The client inherits the System.ServiceModel.ClientBase class, instantiated as Autofac module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution is quite simple.

When setting the DateTime value you need to specify its kind:

```cs
birthDate = model.Birthdate.SpecifyKind(DateTimeKind.Utc);
```